# multiple parameters from variables in Process Task Editor

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing

This is driving me potty.

I'm trying to pass two SSIS variables to a command line executable using an Execute Process Task object.

No matter what I try, the values are not being passed through.

This is how it is set currently:

[image: SSIS example]

The variables are in scope and are of type string (representing integer values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sods law came into effect after posting this question. I tried evaluating my variables as an expression and assigning the resulting string to the arguments property.

I don't see why this would work over the example I gave, but it does, so I'm using that.

Comment: I need to pass two variables to my Process Task. Executable file  and a second parameter which is input for the executable file. How to configure two parameters in the process task editor?